# "lein test :only foo.bar.test/testme" not picking up function "testme" if "test-ns-hook" defined?

Tags: unit-testing, clojure, leiningen

I have defined a Clojure namespace with test functions and want to run them using Leiningen 2.9.1 via `lein test`.

The test functions are organized hierarchically. If I just run `lein test`, all the `deftest` will be picked up, leading to test duplication. For example:

```
(ns foo.bar.test
   (:require
      [clojure.test         :as t]
      [clojure.spec.alpha   :as s]
      [foo.bar.main         :as sut])) ; system under test

(t/deftest test-strip-empty
   (t/is
      (s/valid? ::sut/a-spec some-value)))

(t/deftest test-strip-several-squares
   (t/is
      (s/valid? ::sut/a-spec some-value)))

; collect subtests

(t/deftest testcollect-strip
   (test-strip-empty)
   (test-strip-several-squares))
```

`lein test` would run all three `deftest` entries, thus running `test-strip-empty` and `test-strip-several-squares` twice.

The function `test-ns-hook` can be defined to explicitly call the "top of the test tree".

```
(defn test-ns-hook []
   (testcollect-strip))
```

If exists, `lein test` will only call `test-ns-hook`:

Which is nice!

But once it exists, I cannot ran individual tests anymore.

> ```
> lein test :only foo.bar.test/test-strip-several-squares
>
> lein test foo.bar.test
>
> Ran 0 tests containing 0 assertions.
> 0 failures, 0 errors.
> ```

Not nice!!

Remove the definition of `test-ns-hook` and it works:

> ```
> lein test :only foo.bar.test/test-strip-several-squares
>
> ... 
>
> Ran 1 tests containing 1 assertions.
> 1 failures, 0 errors.
> Tests failed.
> ```

Can happyness be maximized by combining both features: leaving `test-ns-hook` defined and being able to run individual tests?

Comment: Do you want to segregate your tests?  Might be easier done with selectors then.

Comment: @cfrick I found https://jakemccrary.com/blog/2019/01/28/how-to-use-leiningen-test-selectors-to-filter-by-test-name/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't group your tests like with `testcollect-strip`.  I would call this an antipattern.

You can make individual assertions hierarchical within a single `deftest` form using the `testing` macro:  https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.test/testing

```
(deftest t-math
  (testing "Arithmetic"
    (testing "with positive integers"
      (is (= 4 (+ 2 2)))
      (is (= 7 (+ 3 4))))
    (testing "with negative integers"
      (is (= -4 (+ -2 -2)))
      (is (= -1 (+ 3 -4))))))
```

---

> ```
> ~/expr/demo > lein clean ; lein test
>
> lein test _bootstrap
>
> -------------------------------
>    Clojure 1.10.0    Java 12
> -------------------------------
>
> lein test tst.demo.core
>
> Ran 2 tests containing 4 assertions.
> 0 failures, 0 errors.
> ```

You can also use *test selectors* to run only a subset of tests:

> ```
> ~ > lein help test
> Run the project's tests.
>
> Marking deftest or ns forms with metadata allows you to pick selectors to
> specify a subset of your test suite to run:
>
>     (deftest ^:integration network-heavy-test
>       (is (= [1 2 3] (:numbers (network-operation)))))
>
> Write the selectors in project.clj:
>
>     :test-selectors {:default (complement :integration)
>                      :integration :integration}
>
> Arguments to this task will be considered test selectors if they are keywords,
> otherwise arguments must be test namespaces or files to run. With no
> arguments the :default test selector is used if present, otherwise all
> tests are run. Test selector arguments must come after the list of namespaces.
>
> A default :only test-selector is available to run select tests. For example,
> `lein test :only leiningen.test.test/test-default-selector` only runs the
> specified test. A default :all test-selector is available to run all tests.
>
> Arguments: ([& tests])
> ```

So, adding metadata to the test definition

```
(deftest ^:basic-math t-math
  (testing "Arithmetic"
    (testing "with positive integers"
      (is (= 4 (+ 2 2)))
      (is (= 7 (+ 3 4))))
    (testing "with negative integers"
      (is (= -4 (+ -2 -2)))
      (is (= -1 (+ 3 -4))))))
```

And declaring test selector `:basics` to grab everything tagged with `:basic-math` in `project.clj`:

```
(defproject foo.bar "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  ...
  :test-selectors {:basics :basic-math})
```

One can now run only the tests tagged with `:basic-math` via:

> ```
> ~ > lein test :basics
> ```

There is another trick to keep in mind.  The namespace structure of your test code (dirs/files) doesn't need to match that of your source code.  You could have a single source code ns `super.calc`, but a whole hierarchy of testing namespaces.  I prefix them all with a root `tst.` prefix, which I think leads to a nicer naming structure than sticking a `_test` suffix on everything:

```
tst.super.calc
tst.super.calc.add
tst.super.calc.add.int
tst.super.calc.add.int.pos
tst.super.calc.add.int.neg
tst.super.calc.add.float
tst.super.calc.add.float.pos
tst.super.calc.add.float.neg
tst.super.calc.mult
...
```

So you can get as fine-grained as you desire.  Mixing this with lein test selectors allows nearly infinitely fine-grained control.

---

**Also,**

Please checkout lein-test-refresh, my favorite way of doing testing in lein

https://github.com/jakemcc/lein-test-refresh

Comment: Thanks. There is a lot of info to unpack.